# WPF C# Экспорт данных DataGrid в Word

Tags: wpf

Всем привет, как сделать экспорт данных в WPF из DataGrid в Microsfot office word, использую Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. Делал шаблон документа и заменял значения через код, как тоже самое сделать с таблицей брав данные из DataGrid?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно перенести данные в Ворд из ДатаГрида, при этом и нарисовать таблицу в ворде то нет такого пути, реализовать который можно 2 строками. Придется через средства библиотеки mocrosoft.interop.word рисовать, а потом переносить туда данные. Если же надо просто перелить в ворд в строку данные из таблицы, то банальный перебор всех ячеек в одну переменную и заливка этого добра в документ. Уточните, вам нужно таблицу в ворде делать?

Comment: Да таблицу в ворде, перенести данные из DataGrid

Comment: http://nullpro.info/2012/rabotaem-s-ms-word-iz-c-chast-3-rabota-s-tablicami/ тут можно найти тутор по созданию и редактированию таблиц.
Алгоритм я вижу такой, вы программно считаете колво строк и столбцов в ДатаГриде перед формированием документа и методом перебора строк и столбцов записываете все данные в массивы, потом используя эти данные формируете таблицу уже в доке и запоняете ее из массивов

Comment: Я видел это =) У меня опыта мало, но там вроде бы под WinForm и не очень подходит под WPF с его DataGrid

Comment: Под WPF перебор таблицы надо отдельно гуглить, попробуйте по моей ссылке построить таблицу в ворде, можете создать новый проект и чисто потренироваться, а дальше преступайте к Датагриду

Comment: Можете написать мне в инсту (она указана в профиле) и мы найдем опорные точки. А вообще я тут от нечего делать на карантине начал по WPF туторы писать, можете посмотреть, для начинающих будет интересно наверное https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCn_2YmDoZAZh5H-oDrs8S3g/